# ActionScript 3 - Initiating A Bullet Changes Direction With Character

Tags: flash, move, direction, bullet

I'm working on a side scroller that has a character that fires a bullet every time you hit spacebar, the problem I'm having is moving the bullet in the direction the character is facing (left or right).

I have a few of boolean variables to tell me which direction my character is facing: walkingRight | walkingLeft, so if my walkingRight == true, I want the bullet to travel +=10, and walkingLeft == true, bullet -= 10.

The problem is, when I fire facing left, the bullet moves left, but as soon as I turn right, that same bullets starts moving right.

Here is a snippet of AS3 code (Every Frame):

```
if(gamepad.fire2.isPressed){
   // initiate bullet
   var bullet = new Bullet();
   bullet.x = _player.x;
   bullet.y = _player.y;
   /*_boundaries.*/addChild(bullet);
   bullets.push(bullet);
}

for each(var bullet in bullets){
   if(walkingRight || idleRight || jumpingRight){
    bullet.x += 10;
    trace("Bullet - Moving Right");
   }
   else if(walkingLeft || idleLeft || jumpingLeft){
    bullet.x -= 10;
    trace("Bullet - Moving Left");
   }
}
```

I sure would appreciate any help from this as its for a college project.

Thanks

Comment: Once the bullet is created you should store the direction for each individual bullet separately, independent of any info about your main character, either within a custom "myBulletClass.direction" class or vector/array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this:

First create this class:

```
dynamic class BulletWrapper{
     private var bullet:DisplayObject = null;
     public function BulletWrapper( bullet:DisplayObject ){
         this.bullet = bullet;
     }
     public function getBullet():DisplayObject{
         return this.bullet;
     }
}
```

Then modify your code:

```
if(gamepad.fire2.isPressed){
  // initiate bullet
   var bullet = new Bullet();
   bullet.x = _player.x;
   bullet.y = _player.y;
   /*_boundaries.*/addChild(bullet);
   var wrapper:BulletWrapper = new BulletWrapper( bullet );
   //storing as much information as related to bullet animation 
   wrapper.walkingStep = 0;
   wrapper.log = "No move";
   //-------------------------------
   if( walkingRight || idleRight || jumpingRight ){
       wrapper.walkingStep = 10;
       wrapper.log = "Bullet - Moving Right";
   }else if( walkingLeft || idleLeft || jumpingLeft ){
       wrapper.walkingStep = -10;
       wrapper.log = "Bullet - Moving Left";
   }
   //--------------------------
   bullets.push(wrapper);
}

for each(var wbullet:BulletWrapper in bullets){
   var bullet = wbullet.getBullet();
   bullet.x += wbullet.walkingStep;
   trace(wbullet.log);
}
```